# How does iOS choose which app to launch when a generic URL Scheme is launched?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-scheme-url

How does iOS choose which app to launch when a generic URL Scheme is launched ?
What I know from older document is

**Note: If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme.**

OR Is there any latest document that states this ?

Comment: Nope, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple documentation:
To ensure uniqueness, specify a reverse DNS string that incorporates your company’s domain and app name. Although using a reverse DNS string is a best practice, it doesn’t prevent other apps from registering the same scheme and handling the associated links. **Use universal links instead of custom URL schemes to define links that are uniquely associated with your website.**

[image]